# Adding Listeners to different folders in Outlook

Tags: vba, event-handling, listener, outlook-2010

I am trying to add listeners to my main inbox and another folder I have called "AssignNumber." When messages come into my main inbox I have MACRO written that listens for a new mailitem to come in and then does stuff to that item. For my AssignNumber folder on the other hand, I want to be able to drag emails to that folder and once they have been dropped in that folder, that folder listens for them and then performs some other actions that I won't go into. My problem is that all of my code to listen for mail coming in to the MAIN INBOX is written in ThisOutlookSession and I don't know where to add code that listens to the AssignNumber folder. This is the code I have in ThisOutlookSession:

```
    Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

    Private Sub Application_Startup()
       Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
       Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
       Set olApp = Outlook.Application
       Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
       ' default local Inbox
       Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    End Sub

    Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    'do Stuff to mailitem
    End Sub
```

I don't know where/how to add the similar code that will listen to my AssignNumber folder for items that are dragged and dropped into it. 
Can anyone help?? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create multiple listeners for multiple folders as follows:

```
Private WithEvents deletedItems As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents mainInboxItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set deletedItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).Items
    Set mainInboxItems = objNS.Folders("whatever your main mailbox is called").Folders("AssignNumber").Items
    'assumes your "AssignNumber" folder is a subfolder of the main inbox
    'otherwise you can nest Folders("myArchive").Folders("AssignNumber).items etc
End Sub
```

You can do this for as many folders as you want, I'm only using two here but I have close to 10 in my Outlook myself.

You can then assign the `ItemAdd` method to each of them like:

```
Private Sub deletedItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
'do Stuff to mailitem
End Sub
Private Sub mainInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
'do Stuff to mailitem
End Sub
```

All this code can go in ThisOutlookSession.