# Outlook vba - do something when new email arrives to group mailbox (es)

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code bellow (probably from here and to be honest "a little bit" over my VBA skills), which is running in my outlook, and when new email arrives in group mailbox it does something (save attachements this part is extra long so I removed it), than delete the email. It works very well.
Now I need to apply this for two shared boxes. Foolish me thoght that I just add there something like

```
 Set olInboxItems2 = GetFolderPath("GroupBox2\Inbox").Items
```

to line 7, but apparently. It does not work. Any tips how to make this alive appriciated

```
Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim objNS       As NameSpace
    Set objNS = Application.Session
    Set olInboxItems = GetFolderPath("GroupBox1\Inbox").Items
    Set objNS = Nothing
    
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    'On Error Resume Next
    Dim strID       As String
    Dim objMsg      As Outlook.MailItem
    
    strID = Item.EntryID
    Set objMsg = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
    Dim strFile_Path As String
    strFile_Path = "C:\temp\MyTestFile.txt"
    Open strFile_Path For Append As #1
    Write #1, "Start"
    Write #1, Now
    
    Dim objOL       As Outlook.Application
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim lngCount    As Long
    Dim strFile     As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String
    Dim strDeletedFiles As String
    
    ' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
    Set objOL = Application
    
    ' Get the collection of selected objects.
    Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    
    ' The attachment folder needs to exist
    ' You can change this to another folder name of your choice
    '   MsgBox "Email Received"
    '   MsgBox objMsg
    
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    
    If lngCount > 0 Then
        
        ' Use a count down loop for removing items
        ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
        ' confused and only every other item is removed.
        
        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
            
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
            
            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
            
            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
            
        Next i
    End If
    
    objMsg.Delete
    
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    Set objOL = Nothing
    
    Write #1, "Konec"
    Write #1, Now
    Close #1
    
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    
End Sub

Function GetFolderPath(ByVal FolderPath As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim oFolder     As Outlook.Folder
    Dim FoldersArray As Variant
    Dim i           As Integer
    
    On Error GoTo GetFolderPath_Error
    If Left(FolderPath, 2) = "\\" Then
        FolderPath = Right(FolderPath, Len(FolderPath) - 2)
    End If
    'Convert folderpath to array
    FoldersArray = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders.Item(FoldersArray(0))
    If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(FoldersArray, 1)
            Dim SubFolders As Outlook.Folders
            Set SubFolders = oFolder.Folders
            Set oFolder = SubFolders.Item(FoldersArray(i))
            If oFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
            End If
        Next
    End If
    'Return the oFolder
    Set GetFolderPath = oFolder
    Exit Function
    
    GetFolderPath_Error:
    Set GetFolderPath = Nothing
    Exit Function
    
End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Listeners to different folders in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497972/adding-listeners-to-different-folders-in-outlook)

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does your code fail to retrieve the folder? Or do you simply get no events?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method to get any shared folder in Outlook. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared `Calendar` folder). For example:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene")
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```